# Repeat Citations in biblatex phys

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to find a way to cite the same reference twice and have it twice in the bibliography list with a different number. This is because I need to have increasing numbers throughout the document even if they refer to the same reference.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys,sorting=none,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{Ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{refsection}[Ref.bib]
    This is a test to cite \autocite{ref1} and cite \autocite{ref2} and cite \autocite{ref1}.

    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

This shows as

> This is a test to cite1 and cite2 and cite1.

and I would like to have

> This is a test to cite1 and cite2 and cite3.

with three different entries in the Bibliography (with 1 and 3 being displayed as exactly the same).

Can anybody help?

The content of Ref.bib is

```
@article{ref1,
  title={REF1},
  journal={ournal REF1},
  pages={137--153},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Pub REF1}
}


@article{ref2,
  title={REF2},
  author={Author, Test2},
  }
```

The solution I am currently using uses footnotes and endnote. The problem with this, in addition to getting a constant warning, is that the references are not displayed as nicely as when the bibliography is used. If there were a way to achieve this with \printbibliography it would make things so much more neat.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}

%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid,sorting=none,     autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{Ref.bib}

\let\footnote=\endnote %For footnotes at the end 
\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{refsection}[Ref.bib]

This is a test to cite \autocite{ref1} and cite \autocite{ref2} and cite   \autocite{ref1}.

\newpage
\theendnotes
%\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

This can be tried with these two references in ref.bib

```
@article{ref1,
title={REF1},
journal={ournal REF1},
pages={137--153},
year={2015},
publisher={Pub REF1}
}


@article{ref2,
title={REF2 when the title is very long to cover two lines the references are not displayed very nicely},
author={Author, Test2},
}
```

Comment: The same bib entrie twice in bib? Why? A workaround could be to use the same bib entrie with different labels/bib key?

Comment: I am after an automatic solution unfortunately because I have to apply this to a long existing document with a lot of citations.

Comment: Where does this strange way to build a bibliography come from? Are you sure this is exactly what you need? If you cite an item _n_ times, has it to be added to the bibliography _n_ times?

Comment: Are you sure you really need this. That would be highly unusual. You could use fullcites in endnotes instead of `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Yes. This is used in some business journals where citations and I have to follow this structure for a long report. You can see as an example

Comment: Yes. This is used in some business journals where citations and I have to follow this structure for a long report. You can see journal as an example (https://rusi.org/publication/rusi-journal)
Citations are presented in the form of notes at the end of the document and the numbering is always increasing even if the citation is the same. The solution I am currently using is similar to what moewe suggested (footnotes and endnotes). The problem with this is that the references are not displayed very nicely. There second line of the citation is not dented as nicely as when the bibliography is used

Comment: see this\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}

%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid,sorting=none, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{Ref.bib}

\let\footnote=\endnote %For footnotes at the end 
\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{refsection}[Ref.bib]

This is a test to cite \autocite{ref1} and cite \autocite{ref2} and cite \autocite{ref1}.

\newpage
\theendnotes
%\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}

Comment: @article{ref1,
  title={REF1},
  journal={ournal REF1},
  pages={137--153},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Pub REF1}
}


@article{ref2,
  title={REF2 when the titke is very long to cover two lines the references are not displyed very nicely},
  author={Author, Test2},
  }

Comment: @Alessio Please don't post code in comments but edit your question to add it.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `biblatex-chicago` when in the title you mention `biblatex-phys`? What warnings do you get? How is the output not as nice as it could be? What needs to be changed?

Comment: I am currently using biblatex-chicago but the commented verbose-ibid is also ok (they are very similar for what I have seen). I get the ibid but that's acceptable for me. I suggested phys in the question as it displays the numbers in the list of bibliography in a similar way to notes. The style is not a real major constraint though, the key question is how to force the numbers to increment in a numeric-like style even if the citation is the same? Is there a way to show the pdf output here so I can show the differences in the actual output?

Comment: PS just to clarify further, the reason why I am not using a numeric-like style with endnotes is because I need to have the full citation in the notes rather than the number of the citation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use endnotes with footfullcite.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\refname}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, sorting=none, notetype=endonly]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{endfull}[f]{\footfullcite}{\footfullcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=endfull}

\begin{document}
This is a test to cite \autocite{sigfridsson} and cite \autocite{worman} and cite \autocite{sigfridsson}.

\theendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

The `\printbibliography` is just for comparison of output.

---

You can also use the `enotez` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name = {\refname}}
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}
{
  format = \normalfont\normalsize,
}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, sorting=none, notetype=endonly]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{endfull}[f]{\footfullcite}{\footfullcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=endfull}

\begin{document}

This is a test to cite \autocite{sigfridsson} and cite \autocite{worman} and cite \autocite{sigfridsson}.

\printendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, OK that's displayed as I already have with the existing solution (beside the ibid for two consecutive refs). I would like the endnotes solution to be displayed as the bibliography solution. For example in ref 1 "charges from" the word "from" is aligned vertically with "E". That's what I would like. It does not happen with endnotes where "charges" is much more on the left than "E."

Comment: The enotez seems perfect !

Comment: I am going to try it in the full document now... but many thanks!